# dotnet core running in docker container stuck and log NUL character

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I'm running my dotnet core application(.net 5) in docker containers.
sometimes the application stucks, if I check the docker log, it's NUL(Not string NULL) without any exception or errors.

No exception, no error, any ideas about this?
[image]